# Probability of picking a power from $[1,1000]$.

Tags: probability

Consider the following problem, from Rozanov's probability book:

> A whole number from 1 to 1000 is chosen at random. What is the
>   probability of its being a power (higher than the first) of another
>   whole number? Hint. $31^2<1000<32^2$.

My approach:

- since $31^2<1000<32^2$, in the interval $[1,1000]$ there are 30 numbers greater than 1 that are a square.
- since $10^3\le1000<11^3$, in the interval $[1,1000]$ there are 9 numbers greater than 1 that are a cube.
- the fourth powers are also squares, so these do not count.
- fifth powers. Only $2^5$ and $3^5$ are smaller than 1000. $4^5=2^{10}>1000$.
- sixth powers are also squares and cubes.
- among the seventh powers, only $2^7$ is smaller than 1000.

So summing up, we have $1+30+9+2+1=43$ numbers $\le1000$ which are a power of some other number.

I would say that the probability required by the exercise is: $\frac{43}{1001}$.

However, the solution is given as $\frac{1}{25}$.

Comment: Some cubes are squares.  $4^3$, for instance.

Comment: Also notice that there are $1000$ numbers to pick from, not $1001$. $\frac1{25}=\frac{40}{1000}$, so this tells you that you've overcounted by precisely three.

Comment: Also:  don't write things like $10^3<1000$.

Comment: Note:  Perhaps they meant to exclude $1$.  If so, I agree with the answer.  If not, I get $\frac {41}{1000}$.

Comment: Why did you add the first $1$? Why is the solution not just $n_{squares}+n_{cubes}+\ldots+n_{7}=30+9+1=40$?

Comment: @Jam:  $1^2=1,$ so $1$ is a perfect power.  I suspect the problem setter did not count it, though.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, that makes sense. I'd have interpreted "power of another whole number" as "power of a *different* number" but I guess that's not really made explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gathering from the comments:  There are $1000$ numbers in your range, so the denominator should be $1000$, not $1001$.  You counted $2^6$ and $3^6$ twice, once as squares and once as cubes. Although $1$ is a perfect power, it is not a power of another whole number.  I think that phrase was meant to exclude $1$.  Deducting $3$ from your count gives the book answer.